# How can I reach higher fps when I perform animation in WinForms?(How to reduce "cycletime" in my code?)

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, frame-rate

First, I apologize for my poor English skills and wrong usages of grammar.

I was building a project as my schoolwork which want us to show animation on screen, so I decided to use WinForms in C# to achieve this.

However, After I put two or three images and draw some lines the animation become lagging and get low fps. Therefore, I add two stopwatches to record "drawing time" and "time between every drawing" and comment out parts that adding images and drawing, and I get 0 millisecond for drawing part (this is reasonable because I comment out the part) and get around 15 milliseconds between drawing (I think this is not reasonable that it take so long for nothing !?)

I hope that my animation runs in 60 fps, which means it can only take 16~17 milliseconds between every drawing. However, I can only add a few things if I want to meet this demand.

Can anyone explain what it does in these 15 milliseconds and Can I reduce these time? Or how can I get higher fps in my animation?
And how can other people show fancy animation in high fps in C#?

I built it in Visual Studio 2017 on my laptop.
Then this is part of my code, if needed, I can try to port full project in here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Animation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch painttime = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch cycletime = new Stopwatch();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            cycletime.Stop();
            painttime.Start();

            //paint whatever you want

            painttime.Stop();
            textBox1.Text = painttime.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = cycletime.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            cycletime.Restart();
            painttime.Reset();
        }

        //ticks every 1 miliseconds
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run above code, the screen shows that "painttime" is 0 milisecond, and "cycletime" is around 15 miliseconds if I draw nothing.

Comment: Call [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update?view=netframework-4.8) after Invalidate. Not that it is a good idea though.

Comment: _//ticks every 1 miliseconds_ : No! - 1) Timer has a resolution of no less than 20-30 ms. 2) Winforms is really bad at animation.

Comment: Even if you could (in WinForms) draw bitmaps at a speed of 60 fps (you cannot), what would be the purpose? Human *eyes* don't *process* that fast. WinForms is a UI framework, not a engine for games.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would look for another way to do animation.

Comment: Se the [ImageAnimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator) class. Not much of a difference in relation to FPS (I don't know why you care about FPS anyway). Or see [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/): it uses DirectX APIs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try they later!